# I tried implementing a modal through the click of an image using Bootstrap but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, image, modal-dialog

Below is how I've written it. Please let me know where I messed up.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x300" alt="Appify image" data-toggle="modal" data-taget="#appify">
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="appify" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="appify">APPIFY</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x300">
                This is Appify, biatch!
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Data target without # i think

Comment: You could perhaps do an onClick event and toggle the modal through jQuery? I've never seen a modal toggled from an img tag...

Comment: You are missing an end </div> also.

Comment: @MinarMnr Thanks a lot it is working now.

Comment: @deckeresq It worked! I wanted to do a little bit of experimenting and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @vZ10 I tried that but # is necessary. Thanks though!

Comment: @RohitRamesh No problem! Looks like the accepted answer is definitely the correct one, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `data-target` on your `img` tag.  Your version is `data-taget="#appify">` but it should be `data-target="#appify">`.

Whole tag:
`<img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x300" alt="Appify image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appify">`

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gx00gswh/